# How to sanitize 12 digit phone numbers in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010, number-formatting

I would like to sanitize the first 6 digits of 12 digit phone numbers in excel. I did use "******" & Right (6) etc if the numbers are in a separate column but the problem is now, I have the numbers mixed with text sometimes two phone numbers in one cell with text and other numbers (dates and time) e.g.: 12/02/2021 05:12:32 545454545454 texttextetxt and 545658585451 texttexttext. What I would like to achieve is :12/02/2021 05:12:32 ******545454 texttextetxt and ******585451 texttexttext.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Can you post some of the actual cell values, phone numbers redacted with 0's? Also, do you have Office 365?

Comment: Use Reged replace through a VBA custom function.

Answer (score 0):

You may use Split and IsNumeric functions to that purpose:

```
    Dim s, r
    s = Split("12/02/2021 05:12:32 545454545454 texttextetxt and 545658585451 texttexttext", " ")
    r = ""
    For i = 0 To UBound(s)
        es = s(i)
        If Len(es) = 12 And IsNumeric(es) Then
          r = r & "******" & Mid(es, 7, 6) & " "
        Else
          r = r & es & " "
        End If
    Next i
    Debug.Print (r) ' Displays 12/02/2021 05:12:32 ******545454 texttextetxt and ******585451 texttexttext
    End Sub
```